# How to calculate index from python networkx by group(attribute)

Tags: python, networkx

I have a table which contains 'from', 'to', 'date' columns.

I want to get any networkx index(e.g. degree, edges, nodes) by 'date'.

In reality there are a lot of date, it's impossible to calculate index by manually.

Is there any way to calculte degree() or edges() based on 'date' ?

Thank you for reading.

Example code is as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'from' : ['1','2','1','3'], 
                   'to' : ['3','3','2','2'], 
                   'date' : ['20200501','20200501','20200502','20200502']})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'from', target = 'to',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph(), edge_attr = 'date')

# It's easy to calculate any index such as 'degree','node','edge'.

G.nodes()
G.degree()
G.edge()

# However, it's not easy to calculate an index based on 'date' column.
```

Comment: What do you mean with "based on date"? What would be your desired result here?

Comment: 'based on date' means 'group by date' such as G.degree() on '20200501', G.degree() on  '20200502'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inspect those edges which contain a certain date as attribute, iterate over the the edges, setting `data=True` and keep the edges that match. Then generate a new graph induced by those edges using [`Graph.edge_subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph.html):

```
edges_from_date_x = [] 
some_date = '20200502'
for *edge, attr in G.edges(data=True):
    if attr['date'] == some_date:
        edges_from_date_x.append((*edge,))

print(edges_from_date_x)
# [('1', '2'), ('3', '2')]
```

Or if you prefer list-comps you could do as suggested by @AKX:

```
edges_from_date_x = [(*edge,) for *edge, attr in G.edges(data=True)
                     if attr['date'] == some_date]
# [('1', '2'), ('3', '2')]
```

Now generate the induced subgraph:

```
# induced subgraph
G_induced = G.edge_subgraph(edges_from_date_x)
# edgelist from the induced subgraph
G_induced.edges(data=True)
#OutEdgeDataView([('1', '2', {'date': '20200502'}), ('3', '2', {'date': '20200502'})])
# same with the nodes
G.nodes()
# NodeView(('1', '3', '2'))
```

Comment: `edges_from_date_x = [edge for *edge, attr in G.edges(data=True) if attr['date'] == some_date]` maybe?

Comment: Sure let's add that too :) I usually go with regular loops when they get a little long. Changed to list of tuples, since that's what `edge_subgraph` expects @AKX